# Did Ahsoka ever see Obi-Wan after TCW season 7?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels

I feel like the answer to this is fairly obvious, but I'm curious if there's any evidence that says otherwise.

**spoilers for TCW season 7 and Rebels and Mandalorian season 2**

At the end of season 7 of The Clone Wars, we see Ahsoka's last interaction with Obi-Wan is when he tells her via hologram that Anakin has killed Dooku.  In the events of the final episodes, Order 66 is enacted and Ahsoka is separated from the remaining Jedi.  In RotS, we can see pretty directly when Obi-Wan leaves his fight with Anakin and retreats to Tatooine, so it doesn't seem like he went looking for Ahsoka, as he probably thought she died.  In the Ahsoka novel, Ahsoka doesn't comment about Obi-Wan at length, but she does think that he died with the Jedi.

In Rebels, we see that Ahsoka is just discovering that Anakin became Vader.  She never mentions Obi-Wan, and she isn't around when Ezra goes searching for him.  Even though she discovers the truth about Anakin, it doesn't seem like she's taken a particular interest in trying to see if Obi-Wan is alive or looking for him.

We can map out Ahsoka's timeline as, after being saved from her final battle with Vader, going to Sabine and then joining her in their search for Ezra.  Season 2 of The Mandalorian takes places about ten years after the end of Rebels, and we see Ahsoka on Corvus searching for Thrawn and, presumably, Ezra.  There are some gaps in this timeline, though - could Ahsoka have interacted with Obi-Wan in the time between diving back through that portal and going to Sabine?  We know that that ending with Ahsoka and Sabine takes place after the Battle of Endor, so by that point Obi-Wan is dead.

I know that the chances of this are pretty small, especially since Ahsoka never knew about Obi-Wan going to Tatooine or openly searched for him, but is there any possibility that Ahsoka and Obi-Wan interacted in the time between Rebels and A New Hope?

Comment: I'm going with unlikely - unless Obiwan became a force ghost and popped up here and there in Ahsoka's travels (between Rebels and the Mandalorian)